# laravel how to insert o a simple many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a `DetailsAttribute` model.

I have a `Actions` model.

The relationship between them is simple many to many.

That is why I created a new `details_attribute_action` table.

code of the models are:

```
class DetailsAttribute extends  Eloquent{
 public function actions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Action', 'details_attribute_action', 'action_id', 'details_attribute_id');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Action extends Eloquent{
   public function detailsAttribute(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('DetailsAttribute', 'details_attribute_action', 'details_attribute_id', 'action_id');
    }
}
```

then when the user want to add a new `detailsAttribute`, he submits a form that has many actions.

I do this:

```
$detailsAttribute = DetailsAttribute::create($data);
```

I also have this actions:

```
$actions = Input::get('action_id')
```

#### please notice that the $actions is an array because the action_id is a name for 4 select(s) in the html

my question is how to add this `$actions` to the `details_attribute_action` ?

Comment: This Laravel drives you crazy Anastasie Laurent.

Comment: @ivanfromer sorry but why would you say that?

Comment: My problem is exactly like this. And drove me crazy. Sry.

Comment: @ivanfromer bty the answer below is useful, just I still need `deczo` to tell me the problem with `updated_at` and `created_at`

Comment: Thank you Anastasie Laurent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57783/discussion-between-ivanfromer-and-anastasie-laurent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will link the models in pivot table:

```
$detailsAttribute->actions()->sync($actions);
```

This is what you need, right?

---

Side note: Again you have wrong fk order in your relations, should be like this:

```
class DetailsAttribute extends  Eloquent{
 public function actions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Action', 'details_attribute_action', 'details_attribute_id', 'action_id');
    }
}

class Action extends Eloquent{
   public function detailsAttribute(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('DetailsAttribute', 'details_attribute_action', 'action_id', 'details_attribute_id');
    }
}
```

for `belongsToMany` it's always like this:

```
belongsToMany('Model', 'table', 'this_model_fk', 'other_model_fk')
```

Comment: This may took about 20 minutes because I have some other problem. Sorry for the delay. However, I will update you as soon as possible +1 anyway

Comment: everything went fine, just one problem, the `created_at` and `updated_at` in the `details_attributes_actions` keep zero, I mean this : `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000` do you know why please?

Comment: `sync` sets both timestamps as expected. Don't know what the problem is this time

Comment: and what should I do please :)?

Comment: Check the queries run, use `attach` and see if that sets the timestamps correctly maybe